# JavaScript - Hide multiple elements(with same id) with one checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So i am trying to hide multiple html elements with one checkbox.

hiding one element works like a charm, but as soon as i have two it hides only the fist one what matches.

Fast demo what i am trying to do :

Checkbox :
 `<input type="checkbox" id="kaartCheck" onclick="kliendikaartF()">`

Element what i am able to show:

```
<p id="kliendi_kaart_olemas_p" style="display:none">Kliendikaart on olemas!</p>
```

and element what i am not able to show : (Basicly the same what is first

```
<p id="kliendi_kaart_olemas_p" style="display:none">Second element shoult apear</p>
```

and js what i am using for that :

```
function kliendikaartF() {
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("kaartCheck");
  var text = document.getElementById("kliendi_kaart_olemas_p");
  if (checkBox.checked == true){
    text.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    text.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

So long story short, i have multiple elements what i would like to hide with one click, i would give them all the same ID : kliendi_kaart_olemas_p and show / hide them with one checkbox.

Comment: Don't use the same id for 2 elements, use a class instead

Comment: ^^ That.  IDs are meant to be unique.  Browsers handle multiple elements with the same ID differently, and they'll change in the future too.  Use classes to do it correctly.

Comment: Thank You for your suggestion, but i just have to say that i know HTML basics, i am just new to JS and i realy did not have any idea that there would be better way to get HTML elements for JS. If you dont want to help out ohters, then maybe just dont comment to get your numbers up. Ty for understanding, and have nice day.

Comment: @Jaanus A person who knows the basics of HTML would be familiar with [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id). In the first paragraph it is said: "_... a unique identifier (ID) which must be unique in the whole document._" And that's from a pure HTML guide, no scripting involved. Also, at that same HTML guide you can read about [class attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class). Naturally you've read this or something similar when you were studying the HTML basics ...

Comment: Ok, lets see here, if you have realy big DB where you handle many orders and invoices then almoust always you have two kind of id-s. Row Id, what is uniqe for each table, also you have something like Order-id  or something similar to get all order rows together. Tought that i aproach to this "Problem" with same way, i did not need thouse ID-s for anything else, so i tought that i give it a try. Yes i asked a stupid question, i am not mad that many ppl pointed out that i should use Class instead, but not all did not say : Go back to html, you ar stupid and doing it wrong.. Ty for attention.

Comment: You're taking the comments too personally, nobody hasn't engaged in name-calling or other harrasment here. CBroe's comment is very generic, maybe it reflects a bit of frustration, but at the same time it's actually a very good advice. EOD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to use `querySelectorAll()` method for select all element by attribute. This will returns array of all element which is matched by attribute and its value. then you have to iterate all one by one in for loop.

```
function kliendikaartF() {
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("kaartCheck");
  var allElements= document.querySelectorAll('[id="kliendi_kaart_olemas_p"]');
  var new_display_value="none";
  if (checkBox.checked == true){
    new_display_value = "block";
  }
  for(i=0;i<allElements.length;i++){
     allElements[i].style.display=new_display_value;
  }
}
```

Comment: I have modified code for querySelectorAll() argument.

Comment: This works like a charm, but now i am influenced by others, and trying to do that with classes instead of ID-s :).

Anyway, you answered  what was asked, and i will call that for answer.

Comment: var allElements= document.querySelectorAll('[class="kliendi_kaart_olemas_p"]');

Also not hard to fix it to use class instead of ID 

Thank you

Comment: @Jaanus If you want to use jQuery you can try something like that too : https://jsfiddle.net/4oxwf0v3/8/ :)

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById` will only return the first element matching that id. 
If you want to select all IDs or classes, use `document.querySelector('#idhere')`

Answer (score 0):

Use a classs name as kliendi_kaart_olemas_p beacuse here You have created id and id is the unique name of an item in the whole page. If you take the id and modify that element It will only update the element which found first.

```
<p class="kliendi_kaart_olemas_p" style="display:none">Kliendikaart on olemas!/p>
```

and

```
<p class="kliendi_kaart_olemas_p" style="display:none">Kliendikaart on olemas!/p>
```

then initailize you varibale like

```
var text = document.getElementsByClassName("kliendi_kaart_olemas_p");
```

Your problem will be solved

Comment: class seems good and better way to fix my issue right way, but sadly now it does not even show one paragraph.